# How to use MVC structure for Identity package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I use Identity package in my project. I can scaffold code Razor for Identity however I want use MVC structure. Then I found a good source and add this to my my project. It works ok.

The problem is the Identity still use the default code, not code I from my source. Such as: when I use role for the page, If the case is not confirmed, it will return to the login page (the code in the login page is the default code of Identity). But I want the code return to: action Login, controller account in my code.

I can navigate to my MVC code in some cases but that's not the way to go. How does the Identity package recognize my MVC code as its own?

This is `program.cs`:

```
using App;
using App.Services;
using m01_Start;
using m01_Start.Models;
using m01_Start.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// add services
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PlanetService>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IdentityErrorDescriber, AppIdentityErrorDescriber>();


// Setup dbcontext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
             string conntectString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppMvcConnectString");
             // System.Console.WriteLine(conntectString);
             options.UseSqlServer(conntectString);
        });

// add identity
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
                       .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()      // add fix add role error
                       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                    //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                       ;

// Config Identity 
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
             options.Password.RequireDigit = false; 
             options.Password.RequireLowercase = false; 
             options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false; 
             options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
             options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;  
             options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1; 
             options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); 
             options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
             options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
             // Cấu hình về User.
             options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = // các ký tự đặt tên user
                 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
             options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;  
             options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;            
             options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;     
             options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        });

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
     app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
     app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.AddStatusCodePage();

app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    areaName: "ProductManage"
);

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

This is source:

https://github.com/xuanthulabnet/razorweb/blob/master/identity.mvc.zip

The code MVC structure Identity:

[image: The code MVC structure Identity]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow this, Hope this help —

1. Create an ASP.NET Core web application with the MVC template by using the dotnet new mvc command or selecting the "ASP.NET Core Web Application" template in Visual Studio and choosing the "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" option.
2. Add the Identity package to your project by using the dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity command or using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
3. Configure the Identity services in the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class by using the services.AddIdentity method. You can specify the user and role classes, password requirements, cookie settings, and other options in this method.
4. Configure the Identity middleware in the Configure method of the Startup class by using the app.UseAuthentication and app.UseAuthorization methods. These methods enable the authentication and authorization features for the MVC requests and responses.
5. Create the necessary controllers, views, and models for the user registration, login, password reset, and other Identity-related actions. You can use the built-in templates or customize them according to your requirements.
6. Use the Authorize attribute or the User property in the controller actions or views to restrict access to certain areas or resources based on the user's role or authentication status.
7. Test the MVC and Identity features by running the application and navigating to the login, registration, and other pages. You can also use the Identity APIs and services in your code to perform more advanced operations, such as user management, claims-based authentication, and external authentication providers.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [this](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) project as a reference. This application is meant to support the free .PDF focusing on the architecture of modern web applications with ASP.NET Core and Azure.

Speaking about your question, the `Identity` is moved to `Identity` area be default and implemented as `Pages` rather than MVC controllers and views. This is demonstrated [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/tree/main/src/Web/Areas/Identity).

This approach is supported by both *cli* or Package Manager Console described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and UI like on the picture below

[image]